# Getting the horizontal offset position of a childNode that is referenced in a loop

Tags: javascript, parent, children

**Using plain JavaScript**, I am trying to get the offset of a given childNode as I loop through the collection.

I have a  container that has a series of text childNodes:

```
var theChildren = document.getElementById( "parentContainer" ).childNodes,
    theChildrenLen = theChildren.length;

for( var i=0; i<theChildrenLen; i++ ) {

    console.log( theChildren[i].offsetLeft );

}
```

I get undefined for this and any other offset reference.

Any one had this come up and found an approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that there is a text node in between each of the children. If you console.log the 'theChildrenLen' variable you will see that it isn't what you are expecting. In order to filter those out you should add an if statement like so:

```
for( var i=0; i<theChildrenLen; i++ ) {
if (theChildren[i].nodeType !== 3)
   console.log( theChildren[i].offsetLeft );
}
```

This will skip any text nodes that you would normally encounter.

Comment: That is exactly what I have for the most part so text nodes will not return offset values? If I return the entire collection I would get an array, i.e. `["t","e","s","t"]`

Comment: I just verified that TextNode does not have the extensions for measuring on-viewport positioning. Will have to use another solution and maybe inject a span around each TextNode to grab the offset.